MPI_Comm_size always return 1 after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1, I encountered issues with my MPI installation. I am using MPICH and cannot switch to OpenMPI, as it appears to be incompatible a library I use. If I run a C++ program with mpirun -np 4, the result of the function MPI_Comm_size is always 1, while MPI_Comm_rank returns 0.
To highlight the issue, here is a minimal "Hello world" code:
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

std::cout << "Hello from processor " << world_rank;
std::cout << " of " << world_size << std::endl;

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}

To compile, I run the command mpic++ -o hello_world hello_world.cpp. There is apparently no errors. Then, to execute, I use mpirun -np 4 ./hello_world and obtain the following result:
Hello from processor 0 of 1
Hello from processor 0 of 1
Hello from processor 0 of 1
Hello from processor 0 of 1


I tried mpiexec instead of mpirun but it gives the same result. What I am expecting is something like
Hello from processor 2 of 4
Hello from processor 0 of 4
Hello from processor 1 of 4
Hello from processor 3 of 4


I tried to purge the package mpich using apt-get purge mpich, remove everything left with sudo apt-get autoremove and then reinstall it but I got the same result... I also tried to install OpenMPI instead of MPICH and this gave me the expected result with the minimal code given above. Unfortunately I am using MPI with a library (FreeFem) which seems to not support OpenMPI. I cannot compile it if I have the OpenMPI installation. With MPICH, the compilation of the library works, but then I have the same issue as the one outlined above. So I need to fix my MPICH installation. Everything was perfectly working before the Ubuntu upgrade.

AFAICT, this isn't a programming issue per se. You might have better luck on superuser.com or askubuntu.com

Apparently there are some issues with MPICH when upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1. I built it manually from the source and now the hello world code in C++ works as expected. I finally have to make my library work with the new MPICH installation. I hope it will be ok.

The issue is tracked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpich/+bug/2072338 You might add a comment there that it affects your work.
